# VB6 application vs Java 8u60 for Serial Communication

Tags: java, vb6, binary, serial-port, receiver

I am writing a Java application to replace a VB6 application.  The application has to poll a remote system using a 10 byte binary protocol, the response is also a 10 byte binary message where the last byte is a checksum calculated by summing up all the previous bytes.

The problem I'm experiencing is a high number of errors in the Java application where the checksum doesn't match.

The results are quite repeatable.  The VB6 application has virtually no errors, however the Java application has lots.  I've checked the port settings, they are the same 19200,n,8,1.

In VB6 the port is set-up the serial port is set-up as follows:

```
    CDTimeout = 0
    CommPort = 1
    CTSTimeout = 0
    DSRTimeout = 0
    DTREnable = False
    EOFEnable = False
    Handshaking = None
    InBufferCount = 0
    InBufferSize = 1024
    Index = 0
    InputLen = 0
    InputMode = comInputModeBinary
    Interval = 1000
    Name = "comInterfaceUnit"
    NullDiscard = False
    OutBufferSize = 512
    ParityReplace = "?"
    RThreshold = 10
    RTSEnable = False
    Settings = "19200,n,8,1"
    SThreshold = 0
    Tag = ""
```

The javax.comm SerialPort set-up is as follows:

```
    baudrate = 19200
    closed = false
    databits = 8
    dtr = false
    flowcontrol = 0
    framing = false
    framingByte = 0
    framingByteReceived = false
    name = "COM1"
    nativeHandle = 324295048
    notifyMask = 1
    parity = 0
    rcvThreshold = -1
    rcvTimeout = -1
    rts = true
    startBI = false
    stateCD = false
    stateCTS = false
    stateDSR = false
    stateFE = false
    stateOE = false
    statePE = false
    stateRI = false
    stopBits = 1
```

In VB6 the event handler just copies the receive bytes into a byte array and thats exactly what the Java code does via the SerialEvent.

Java checksum computation:

```
int intChecksumInPkt = (int)(arychrMsg[RESPONSE_LENGTH -1] & 0xff) ,intCalcChecksum = 0; 
for( int b=0; b<RESPONSE_LENGTH -1; b++ ) { 
    intCalcChecksum += (int)(arychrMsg[b] & 0xff); 
} 
intCalcChecksum &= 0xff; 
if ( intCalcChecksum == intChecksumInPkt ) { ... }
```

VB6 checksum code:

```
intSum = 0
For intI = gintInterfaceUnitReplyStatusOffset To gintInterfaceUnitReplyData8Offset
    intSum = intSum + CInt(gbytInterfaceUnitReplyArray(gintCommPortIndex, intI))
Next intI
If gbytInterfaceUnitReplyArray(gintCommPortIndex, gintInterfaceUnitReplyChecksumOffset) = CByte(intSum And &HFF) Then
    ' Match, so a 'good' message.
    blnFunctionValue = True
End If
```

Comment: I suspect the error elsewhere. Can you add the checksum-calculation method(s)? And the receiving parts also ...

Comment: The checksum is very simple, starting at the first byte in the packet, sum up until the last byte in the packet, excluding the checksum in the packet which is the last byte.

Comment: Simple, yet there is a lot of space for error when "translating" to java. But I do not want to speculate without having seen the actual code used. Often there are casting-issues. Been there, done that - went crazy and learned something. I would first do this: check if the same data sent will result in the same data received on both VB6 and Java solutions. Then (secondly) really step it through in a debugger and check when the two sums start to differ from each other.

Comment: I agree, the checksum in java:
        
        int intChecksumInPkt = (int)(arychrMsg[RESPONSE_LENGTH -1] & 0xff)
           ,intCalcChecksum = 0;
        for( int b=0; b<RESPONSE_LENGTH -1; b++ ) {
            intCalcChecksum += (int)(arychrMsg[b] & 0xff);        
        }
        intCalcChecksum &= 0xff;
        if ( intCalcChecksum == intChecksumInPkt ) {
        ...
        }

Comment: Ok, I don't know how an overflow is handled in VB6 ... but I guess you have an overflow ( value > 255) in intCalcChecksum. Then you just cut it off by `& 0xff`. I guess VB6 handles this differently or at least the VB6 implementation of the computation.

Comment: VB6 would throw an error if an overflow is encountered, but in this module it is ignored with a "On Error Resume Next" which causes the checksum calculation to carry on.  However in VB6, it looks like the is also masked with &HFF

Comment: Can you add VB6 code to the question text?

Comment: Not really, sorry, there is so much of it and its a bit of a mess.

Comment: Only the checksum-part, I wanted to say. Can you see what the state of the variable is after "Resume Next" hits? Is the value changed? Would you mind trying `for( int b=0; b<RESPONSE_LENGTH -1; b++ ) { 
    intCalcChecksum += (int)(arychrMsg[b] & 0xff); intCalcChecksum &= 0xff;
} 
 `

Comment: I'll post as an answer so it is formatted and easier to read...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92371/discussion-between-fildor-and-splatten).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem was I didn't call "enableReceiveThreshold".

Works now.